# Time out opening second page in same browser with long running page load

Tags: php, cloudflare

**Scenario:**
 1. A wordpress site backend. 
 2. **Chrome Tab #1:** Open a wordpress backend example: /wp-admin/run-long-php-script/ which runs a long php script which will continue to load for a long time.
 3. **Chrome Tab #2:**  While tab #1 is running open another tab #2 on same Google browser and access any page from the same wp backend example: /wp-admin/edit.php
 4. Chrome Tab #2 cannot load and will time out. It can only load properly when Chrome tab #1 php execution finish its task.
 5. **Firefox Tab #1:** While Chrome tab #1 php long script is still running, use Firefox browser to open any page from the same wp backend example: /wp-admin/edit.php, the page will load properly with no issue (no time out). 
 6. The case is same vice versa with chrome and firefox browser.
 7. Domain is running trough cloudflare with no cache on /wp-admin/*
8.  Site is using php fpm 7.3

**Question:**
What is going on here and how to solve it? Or if unclear, how to find the origin of the issue?

Comment: Maybe you want to add information on what the long running script is doing, it might be relevant? Maybe you want to look at the Network tab in the browser developer tools and see exactly where the page load is waiting, and add that to the question?

Comment: I suspect this may have something to do with cloudflare. The scenario happens after I upgraded cloudflare to pro. The other site using cloudflare free does not have this issue. Problem is I am not sure if it is my server queing cloudflare IP or this can be some cloudflare settings? The time out says 524 cloudflare says my server is not reachable.

Comment: Are you sure the function *(php script)* is flawless? Does all work in another enviroment *(sandbox)* flawless? The diff in normal/pro options should actually nothing change in already existing settings, it adds normally extra options which perhaps have to be tweaked also?

Comment: @Charles  Hi, I tested the same script to run on 2 different sites on the same browser opening at the same time at different tabs. Site A experience the time out issue but site B not experiencing the time out issue. Even tested a different process, the wordpress original saving post function (which runs for 20 - 30 seconds), the situation is the same for both sites, site A problem, site B no problem.The difference wih site A and Site B is the hosting server and the cloudflare account.

Comment: @mozboz checked the Network Tab of /wp-admin/edit.php when another long running script is opened on another tab, all it says is "edit.php Pending".

Answer (score 0):

2 possibilities that I could find by quick search :

1. If session is written to file, then for request from same useragent may be queued at server [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430883/simultaneous-requests-to-php-script?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. [Max number of parallel connections per browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser) - See 2020 updates

Please share if any of this gives any way to the solution.

Comment: I suspect this may have something to do with cloudflare. The scenario happens after I upgraded cloudflare to pro. The other site using cloudflare free does not have this issue. Problem is I am not sure if it is my server queing cloudflare IP or this can be some cloudflare settings? The time out says 524 cloudflare says my server is not reachable.